# .NET 5.0 options pattern using JSON array

Tags: c#, configuration, appsettings

I am building a C# .NET 5.0 application to talk to an external API for which we have multiple accounts that we can post data to. I am trying to store these details in `appsettings.json` file and use the options pattern to retrieve the settings.

I have the following structure in my app settings.json

```
"SomeApi": {
    "Url": "https://api.someapi.net/v3/",
    "Secret": "mysecretvlaue",
    "ClientId": "myclientid",
    "Accounts": [
      {
          "Name": "Bob",
          "Username": "HisUsername",
          "Password": "HisPassword",
          "PostingLocation": "HisLocation"
      },
      {
          "Name": "Fred",
          "Username": "HisUsername",
          "Password": "HisPassword",
          "PostingLocation": "HisLocation"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have a class set up like this:

```
public class SomeApiOptions
    {
        public const string SomeApi = "SomeApi";
   
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Secret { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Account
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Username { get; set; }
        string Password { get; set; }
        string PostingLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

My startup.cs has this:

```
services.Configure<SomeApiOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(SomeApiOptions.SomeApi));
```

Finally, I inject `IOptions` to the class where I need to use the settings like so:

```
Public MyClass (IOptionsSnapshot<SomeApiOptions> options)
```

The issue I am having is the `Accounts` never get populated with their respective values.
`Url`, `Secret` etc. are populated and the number of elements items in the `Accounts` list is correct, but all of the properties have null values.

I have looked at similar questions and tried restructuring my JSON a few ways but still end up with null values.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see a couple of problems here. First, none of the properties in the `Account` class are public so you need to change that. Second, the `Location` property doesn't match the JSON which is `PostingLocation`.

Comment: In JSON there is property called `PostingLocation` while its name in object is `Location` try to make them same or... add data Annotation to your object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here.

First, none of the properties in the `Account` class are public so you need to change that:

Second, the `Location` property doesn't match the JSON which is `PostingLocation`. Your class should be:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PostingLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, I have edited the post to reflect the `PostingLocation` is as you describe.

Comment: The properties still need to be public though, that's your real problem.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that. Public properties solved the issue immediately.